# How to use like in stored procedure with int parameter?

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I 've used the Query Builder tool of Visual Studio 2008 to build a stored procedure. This is the preview script:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
             FROM sysobjects 
            WHERE name = 'SelectQuery' AND user_name(uid) = 'dbo')
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.SelectQuery
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SelectQuery
(
    @StudentID int
)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT        StudentID, StudentName, StudentPhone, StudentAddress, 
              StudentBirthDay, StudentDescription, StudentStatus
FROM            tbl_Student
WHERE        (StudentID LIKE '%' + @StudentID + '%')
GO
```

But when I tried to execute it, I got an error:

```
Error Message: Conversion fail when converting the value '%' to datatype int.
```

Please help me!

Comment: Can you describe the purpose of this query? Are you trying to do a partial string match (that would be the only time you would need the wildcards)

Comment: What do you want to apply a LIKE for with an INT ?? Doesn't make sense.... either the INT matches - or not. There's no "LIKE" an int...... what are you trying to do here??? Please explain in more detail.....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to find rows where `@StudentID` is a substring of `StudentID`? If so

```
WHERE StudentID LIKE '%' + cast(@StudentID as varchar(10)) + '%'
```

Should work.

Answer (score 1):

'%' can not be used with integer data type. Why would you need '%' when you have absolute studentID? Just compare it with '='.

If you really insist on using '%', then you have to change data type of studentID to varchar or something like that.

Comment: Presumably the OP wants to find rows where `@StudentID` is a substring of `StudentID`. `=` wouldn't work for this.

Comment: @Martin: Could be that scenario. But don't you think he has got his design wrong, if that's the scenario?

Comment: I was just thinking about that. Probably yes! The only time I could see it being vaguely useful would be if there was some front end that allowed operators to type in a fragment of a studentid rather than a whole id. Even that would be quite questionable as obviously all queries would end up with a scan rather than a seek.

Answer (score 1):

I think you actually need this

```
WHERE RIGHT(StudentID,12) LIKE '%' + RIGHT(@StudentID,12) + '%'
```

In case you are wondering, RIGHT implicitly converts non-varchar data to varchar.  A more proper way would be to use CONVERT explicitly, but as you can see, it is longer.

```
WHERE (VARCHAR(20),StudentID) LIKE '%' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@StudentID) + '%'
```

**As Martin points out**, LIKE implicitly converts the LHS. Don't think I ever tried it that way but it works

```
declare @studentid int set @studentid = 205

;with tmp as (select 201102050001 studentid)
select * from tmp
WHERE StudentID LIKE '%' + RIGHT(@StudentID,12) + '%'

-> output: 201102050001
```

Comment: `LIKE` forces an implicit conversion anyway. And why 12? The max value for an int is `2147483647`? (I can see 11 would deal with potential `-` characters)

Comment: NB: The implicit conversion that `LIKE` does is also to `varchar(12)` but I can't see the reason!

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to go around this would be to convert StudentID to a varchar. Just use `CONVERT(varchar, StudentID)`.

Comment: That wouldn't fix the OP's error. This is coming from the `'%' + @StudentID + '%'` concatenation.